# How do you find the RULE associated to a column?

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Database that has some Table and in that table there's a Column.

I'm using NHibernate to do an update to a record, when I get this exception saying I'm violating some RULE on the column.

I do some research to find out there's a RULE associated with that column in the database, but I have **no idea** how to find this rule, see what it does, etc.

Does anyone know how to show the rules for a column? Or just all the rules in the database, anything to get me heading in the right direction.

** EDIT **

The exact error message is:

> A column insert or update conflicts
>   with a rule imposed by a previous
>   CREATE RULE statement. The statement
>   was terminated.  The conflict occurred
>   in database '[MYDB]', table
>   '[MYTABLE]', column '[MYCOLUMN]'.

Comment: what is the exact error message you are getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do `sp_help TableName`.  It will return a number of resultsets, one of which (the 7th one) shows the contraints on the table.

You can also inspect the other resultsets for not nullable columns, identity columns, etc.

Comment: That helped a lot, thanks! I was able to find the rule in the constraints like you said.

Answer (score 4):

Look in SQL Server Management Studio.

Connect to the SQL Server, browse to the database, then open the programmability section.
Go to the rules folder, and that will list all the rules in the database.

Comment: This is great, helps me manage the rules so I can see what else might be lurking underneath it all.